# Want to create Bridged network from Windows host to Fedora guest in VBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dns, fedora

I have a Fedora virtual machine in VirtualBox, and I want to use Bridged Network Adapter for Internet connection.

What do I have to do to achieve this?

I have selected Bridged adapter from the Network menu in VirtualBox.

My Address on the host machine is configured statically. And I have no access to DHCP from my host machine.

Lets say my host machine IP information is-:

```
IP Address: 1.2.3.4
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 5.6.7.8

DNS: 8.8.8.8
```

I am on Windows 8.1 running a Fedora 24 guest. Is it possible to use Bridged Network Adapter for internet access ?

**Please note my ISP allocates a static private IP per customer. That is every customer has an unique IP in the subnet.**

Comment: @techraf My host machine IP information.

Comment: And you are aware that `5.6.7.8` gateway makes no sense with `1.2.3.4` address, right?

Comment: @techraf Thats just an example. I did'nt want to put my actual IP Address here.

Comment: You can make an example that makes sense and an example that doesn't make sense. Yours doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

> What do I have to do to achieve this?

You need just to set a static configuration on your Fedora in the same network as your host (as your example host configuration makes no sense, I assume `192.168.1.1` to be the gateway address). Basically with bridged networking only the IP address of the machine will differ between the host and the guest.

Assuming the host configuration is:

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.4
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.1.1
DNS: 8.8.8.8
```

You can set guest to:

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.5
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.1.1
DNS: 8.8.8.8
```

If you have one interface you need to set the following in `ifcfg-eth0` file (refer to the [documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html#s2-networkscripts-interfaces-eth0)):

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=1.2.3.5
USERCTL=no
GATEWAY=1.2.3.5
DNS1=8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Is 192.168.1.1 the default gateway on my host system or is it the IP of the host system.

Comment: The default gateway is the same on the host and guest.

Comment: No it didn't work. When I put in an IP say 172.16.130.197 I couldn't access my network since my ISP gives out connections based on IPs which means that IP is reserved for someone else. So what IP do I provide ?

Comment: Also there is no seperate NIC showing up in my host operating system, when I go to "Open Network and Sharing" -> "Adapter Settings"

Comment: And why should you have any separate NIC? You asked how to configure a VM with bridged networking and got the answer.

Comment: Well I can't access the internet from my VM, since my ISP allocates a fixed IP per customer. Any ideas on what to do ?